# Container (OU) selections changing in User Profiles Sync in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: active-directory, user-profile-service, profile-sync

I am working with a client who has a SharePoint Server 2010 farm, build level is pre-SP1. They have had User Profile Sync running against two Active Directory Domains for quite some time.

What we are seeing is that the Container (Active Directory OU's) settings are changing within the Synchronization Connection for a domain to selections we know no one selected. It would seem that SharePoint is having trouble keeping track of the Containers we have selected, and losing the settings we input.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?

The infrastructure team is making minor changes to Active Directory, which includes adding and removing OU's. Is SharePoint getting lost due to these type of changes?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the build level, I would venture to say that the changes being made in AD are affecting the UPS process due to a number of issues that have been patched within the UPS process.  A number of updates have corrected problems with the User Profiles which would likely correct this behavior.  Is there a reason that they have not applied updates to this farm?

Comment: They have held off updating due to dependencies on K2.